# How to set min price max price parameters in Nodejs Mongodb, and get data from these queries posted through postman

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express

How to set min price max price parameters in Nodejs Mongodb, and get data from these queries posted through postman.

```
  if (req.query.max_price && req.query.max_price != "") {
      qry.price = { $lte: req.query.max_price };
  }
```

and

```
if (req.query.max_price && req.query.max_price != "") {
     qry.price = { $lte: req.query.max_price };
}
```

But it doesn't follow the parameters given like min_query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all, you must parse the query input to Int or Float.
here is a sample of the code :

```
const max = parseInt(req.query.max, 10);
Models.Collection.find({price: {$lte: max}});
```

Comment: In my MongoDB model, I had set ''price'' as a string, I used your suggestion and converted it into an integer using parseInt, but nothing really changed